# Epiphany framework redirects to homepage

Tags: php, epiphany

Hello so I've started using epiphany microframework and is having simple problem. I followed the [docs](https://github.com/jmathai/epiphany) but I can't get the route to work. Here is my code:

```
include_once 'src/Epi.php';
Epi::init('route');
getRoute()->get('/', 'home');
getRoute()->get('/contact', 'contactUs');
getRoute()->run();

function home() {
    echo 'You are at the home page';
}

function contactUs() {
    echo 'Send us an email at <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a>';
}
```

and running it on terminal with `php -S localhost:8080`. Whenever I enter `localhost:8080` it echos out `'You are at the home page'`. But when I do `localhost:8080/contact` it still echos out `'You are at the home page'`. I've followed everything in the docs. Am I doing something wrong?